# CKEditor on Opencart Order Page?

Tags: ckeditor, opencart

I'm trying to get ckeditor to be displayed on the admin > order history page but doesn't seem to be making much progress.

I added the following lines into admin/view/template/sale/order_info.tpl

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/view/javascript/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        CKEDITOR.replace('comment_editor']; ?>', {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
            filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
            filebrowserUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
            filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>'
        });
        //--></script>
```

Can anyone please share some pointers how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Just use Firebug or other browser Dev tools, it will show you any errors/problems. No need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why you have this bit of code

```
]; ?>'
```

on the `.replace(` line but that shouldn't be there. Removing that should fix it

Comment: Thanks Jay. have removed that but the problem still persists. Any possibility of a page not allowing ckeditor to be displayed or it should work regardless of page as long as it being a textarea?

Comment: correct. The page is irrelevant as long as you've added the basics to it. Using firebug or chrome developer tools should show you what error is causing this to not function

Comment: Hi @bernie Were you able to solve this issue? I was able to add ckeditor to order info -> history -> comments section. I see ckeditor instead of textarea but It doesnt post the comment.